# Unexpected elseif in simple form validation

Tags: php, if-statement

I just made a signup form and I encountered a problem when I added the final validations (the MySQL ones).

This is the error that I get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\includes\signup.php on line 72

Row 72 has been marked to help you figure it out.

```
else
        {
            require_once("db_connect.php");

            // Email validation
            $query_email="SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
            $result_email=mysql_query($query_email) or die (mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_email)>0)
            {
                echo "You already have an account registered on this email.";
            }

            // Username validation
            $query_username="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result_username=mysql_query($query_username) or die (mysql_error());
            elseif (mysql_num_rows($result_username)>0) /* !!! ROW 72 !!! */
            {
                echo "Username already registered. Pick something else";
            }

            // Add new user to database
            else
            {
                $query="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$birthday', '$sex', '', '$registered', '')";
                mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
                echo "User created!";
            }

        }
```

If I comment everything between `// Username validation` and `// Add new user to database` everything works OK (except for the fact that I don't have a username validation).

In case you wonder what $username is:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

I've read some of the questions on SO about unexpected elseif but I just don't get it in my case. The brackets seem alright and elseif is supplied with a condition. Please let me know before downrating so I can edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: you can't have code in between your if statement and your elseif statement

Comment: `$query_username="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result_username=mysql_query($query_username) or die (mysql_error());
            ` these 2 lines need to be moved

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Yeah, I know that I should use MySQLi. I'm doing this just for practice, I'll jump to it if I ever use this form on the web. Thank you very much for the "be a better PHP developer link". I had a look and it's really informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
// Username validation
            $query_username="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result_username=mysql_query($query_username) or die (mysql_error());
            elseif (mysql_num_rows($result_username)>0) /* !!! ROW 72 !!! */
            {
                echo "Username already registered. Pick something else";
            }
```

to this:

```
// Username validation
            $query_username="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result_username=mysql_query($query_username) or die (mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_username)>0) /* !!! ROW 72 !!! */
            {
                echo "Username already registered. Pick something else";
            }
```

It is unexpected because `else if` is an else conditional to an initial `if` conditional, sequentially joined by the curly braces in standard format. Your example code here has no initial if conditional.

Your last `else` statement will need some other kind of check to determine if insert is necessary.

Here is an alternative:

```
// Email validation
            $query_email="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' OR username='$username'";
            $result_email=mysql_query($query_email) or die (mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_email)>0)
            {
                echo "There is already an account registered on this email or that username is already taken.";
            }
            else
            {
                // Add new user to database
                $query="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$birthday', '$sex', '', '$registered', '')";
                mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
                echo "User created!";
            }
```

Also, please note that you need to sanitize this input. I don't know what you're currently doing to ensure $username or $email are not hijack attempts. In addition, mysql_ functions are deprecated. Switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements to sanitize input.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is indeed an alternative. However I managed to fix it by simply moving the variables before the first "if" so that nothing remains between it and "elseif".

Comment: You can do that as well. EIther way the point is that there is code between your conditionals and that can't be that way for else if to work in this case

Comment: Yes. I'm using mysql_real_escape_string so prevent SQL injection. Is that not enough?

Comment: It's not really a matter of enough since mysql_ is deprecated. Switching to mysqli or PDO and using prepared statements is your easiest and best alternative to a quick update. Neither are particularly hard to switch to, but you may find mysqli to be syntactically nearly identical to mysql_ functions.

Comment: I know this is not related to this question but how would my db_connect.php look with mysqli?

Comment: <?php
 define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
 define("DB_USER","root");
 define("DB_PASS", "");
 define("DB_DATABASE","spore_db");
 
 $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
 
 mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: This is how it looks now.

Comment: Just call `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php you can choose to use procedural or object oriented. See the link. Typically you will hear object oriented as a buzz word these days. Personally I think it is easier to manage code under oop principals.

Comment: I changed mysql_connect to mysqli_connect and I get the following warning message: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\includes\db_connect.php on line 9

Comment: right well, check that link. for the official documentation. they have examples for both.